# Merge multiple files preserving the original sequence in unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I have multiple (more than 100) text files in the directory such as

```
files_1_100.txt
files_101_200.txt
```

The contents of the file are name of some variables like `files_1_100.txt` contains some variables names between 1 to 100

```
"var.2"
"var.5"
"var.15"
```

Similarly `files_201_300.txt` contains some variables between 101 to 200

```
"var.203"
"var.227"
"var.285"
```

and `files_1001_1100.txt` as

```
"var.1010"
"var.1006"
"var.1025"
```

I can merge them using the command

```
cat files_*00.txt > ../all_files.txt
```

However, the contents of files does not follow that in the parent files. For example `all_files.txt` shows

```
"var.1010"
"var.1006"
"var.1025"
"var.1"
"var.5"
"var.15"
"var.203"
"var.227"
"var.285"
```

So, how can I ensure that contents of `files_1_100.txt` comes first, followed by `files_201_300.txt` and then `files_1001_1100.txt` such that the contents of the `all_files.txt` is

```
"var.1"
"var.5"
"var.15"
"var.203"
"var.227"
"var.285"
"var.1010"
"var.1006"
"var.1025"
```

Comment: I would recommend renaming them in some known format - like `files_001_100.txt`  & then run cat over them..

Comment: Why not just sort the file/output afterwards ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try it out,  but I think that this will work:

```
ls file*.txt | sort -n -t _ -k2 -k3 | xargs cat
```

The idea is to take your list of files and sort them and then pass them to the cat command.

The sort uses several options:

- -n - use a numeric sort rather than alphabetic
- -t _ - divide the input (the filename) into fields using the underscore character
- -k2 -k3 - sort first by the 2nd field and then by the 3rd field (the 2 numbers)

You have said that your files are named file_1_100.txt, file_101_201.txt, etc. If that means (as it seems to indicate) that the first numeric "chunk" is always unique then you can leave off the `-k3` flag. That flag is needed only if you will end up, for instance, with file_100_2.txt and file_100_10.txt where you have to look at the 2nd numeric "chunk" to determine the preferred order.

Depending on the number of files you are working with you may find that specifying the glob (file*.txt) may overwhelm the shell and cause errors about the line being too long. If that's the case you could do it like this:

```
ls | grep '^file.*\.txt$' | sort -n -t _ -k2 -k3 | xargs cat
```

Comment: It seems this command uses the backup files too i.e. those that end with a tilde(~). Sometimes the editors leave them there as it is even when I close them. Is there a way to ignore that here.

Comment: Added a glob to limit the files to only those starting with "file" and only ending with ".txt" - if you need to be more or less specific, easy enough to change that glob...

Comment: Parsing output from `ls` is error prone as this will break if `file*.txt` contains spaces or newlines.

Comment: True, but part of the "spec" did give us the expected form of the filenames. If OP had not said anything related filename then we would have to allow for it. But since the q was pretty specific on how the filename is formed, I think I am on pretty safe ground...

Comment: Note how every (working) answer assumes underscores between chunks. We're basing that on the first sentence & example in the question...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf` `sort` and pipe that to `xargs cat`:

```
printf "%s\0" f*txt | sort -z -t_ -nk2 | xargs -0 cat > ../all_files.txt
```

Note that whole pipeline is working on NULL terminated filenames thus making sure this command even works foe filenames with space/newlines etc.

Comment: I found that we needed to sort using the third argument -k3 too for the command to work well.

Comment: Yes sure you can do: `printf "%s\0" f*txt | sort -z -t_ -nk2,3 | xargs -0 cat` also.

Answer (score 1):

If your filenames are free from any special characters or white-spaces, then other answers should be easy solutions.
Else, try this [`rename`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=rename) based approach:

```
$ ls files_*.txt
files_101_200.txt  files_1_100.txt

$ rename  's/files_([0-9]*)_([0-9]*)/files_000$1_000$2/;s/files_0*([0-9]{3})_0*([0-9]{3})/files_$1_$2/' files_*.txt

$ ls files_*.txt
files_100_100.txt  files_101_200.txt

$ cat files_*.txt > outputfile.txt

$ rename 's/files_0*([0-9]*)_0*([0-9]*)/files_$1_$2/' files_*.txt
```

Comment: I usually prefer that such filenames should be padded with zeros. Makes sorting easier.

Answer (score 0):

The default sorting behavior of `cat file_*` is alphabetical, rather than numeric.

List them in numerical order and then cat each one, appending the output to some file.

`ls -1| sort -n |xargs -i cat {} >> file.out`

Comment: I think since the filenames of all files starts with alphabet, this solution does not seem to work.

Comment: It didn't work. The output file I got is still 

    "var.1010"
    "var.1006"
    "var.1025"
    "var.1"
    "var.5"
    "var.15"
    "var.203"
    "var.227"
    "var.285"

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a for-loop and adding the files one by one (the -v sorts the files correctly when the numbers are not zero-padded)

```
for i in $(ls -v files_*.txt)
do
    cat $i >> ../all_files.txt
done
```

or more convenient in a single line:

```
for i in $(ls -v files_*.txt) ; do cat $i >> ../all_files.txt ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with Awk by splitting and sorting `ARGV`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    for(i=1; i<=ARGC-1; i++) {
        if(i > 1) {
            j=i-1
            split(ARGV[i], curr, "_")
            split(ARGV[j], last, "_")
            if (curr[2] < last[2]) {
                tmp=ARGV[i]
                ARGV[i]=ARGV[j]
                ARGV[j]=tmp
            }
        }
    }
}1' files_*00.txt
```